# OSX Firefox Pass Arguments to Magnet Protocol Handler

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, protocol, magnet-links

How do I open magnet links in Firefox with a command line app, namely transmission-remote?

I think I need to make a packaged app that accepts arguments, and here's what I did so far:

1. Use Automator to run a shell script with the following:

   `transmission-remote -a $@`
2. Save the Automator script as Transmission.app
3. Choose Transmission.app in Firefox when using it for magnet links

However, pass arguments to this requires:

```
open Transmission.app --args magnet:etc
```

I assume Firefox is doing something like: `Transmission.app %s`, but I can't tell how Firefox is passing arguments to the helper app.  I've also tried creating a wrapper shell script and naming it `helper.app` to no avail.

Alternatively, can Firefox use something like this as a protocol handler, where I can pass in %s?

```
open Transmission.app --args %s
```

EDIT: DS answer apparently works on Snow Leopard and Lion, but I'm still problems with blank arguments being sent from Firefox.  I'll paste my comment here too:

I've tried the following but only blanks are sent: echo "$@" >> ~/somefile and echo "$*" >> ~/somefile with and without quotes. Perhaps it is my Firefox settings (about:config?). I'm on 19.0.2 (latest), OSX 10.8.2 in case anybody else chimes in...

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same question. I got it to work, and I think you were missing a small step. Apparently Firefox on Mac, for its "Open With" applications, doesn't pass arguments via command line or environment variables or any other unix-like method. It uses Mac's [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html). Automator can translate these to command line arguments. The following works on Snow Leopard:

1. Start up Automator, selecting Application for "Choose a template for your workflow".
2. Find the Action "Run Shell Script", and drag or double-click to add it.
3. For "Pass input" dropdown: choose "As arguments" **<-- I think that's the step you are missing.**
4. For "Shell" dropdown: pick the shell you like (probably /bin/sh, judging by your question).
5. Automator will give you a sample of code, but you'll just want what you already have: `transmission-remote -a "$@"` (double-quotes allow correct forwarding of arguments that contain spaces).
6. Save the app.

When Firefox runs this app to open files/downloads, it passes them in Mac's native way, then Automator translates them to shell arguments, and the shell script forwards them to `transmission-remote`.

Comment: Hi DS, thank you for answering.  I did as you suggested, but it doesn't work on Mountain Lion.  Here is my Automator script with "As arguments" dropdown selected: http://i.imgur.com/c8u6zia.png

Comment: I've now tested that it works both on Snow Leopard, and Lion, but don't have Muntain Lion to test on. Try replacing the command with `echo Hello "$@" world` and testing directly in Automator. The only thing I can think of is that "Run Shell Script" action has in Options a box to "Ignore this action's input": make sure that's not accidentally checked.

Comment: I've tried the following but only blanks are sent: `echo "$@" >> ~/somefile` and `echo "$*" >> ~/somefile` with and without quotes.  Perhaps it is my Firefox settings (about:config?).  I'm on 19.0.2 (latest), OSX 10.8.2 in case anybody else chimes in...

Comment: You can test without Firefox by dragging and dropping a file onto your app icon in Finder: new Firefox releases should work the same way (they do for me). You can also try testing within Automator. But sorry, no 10.8 here, so I can't check.